# Tuneup Media plugin for iTunes?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, mp3, window, duplicate

Do anyone have any experience with Tuneup Media plugin for iTunes?

I have thousands of MP3 files and it is really messy all over place. Some in drive E and F. There are a lot of duplicates files in many different folders and incorrect/messy filenames.

I am looking for a way to clean it all up and move music files in a folder with albums folders and fix filenames.

Will Tuneup Media do this?

Comment: I am a paid user of TuneUp and it works for me to a degree. Follow the instructions and only process a few hundred files at a time. It will take a while.

Comment: @RandolphWest But does it create folders too? Like I have a few hundreds in a folder... will TuneUp create some albums folders?

Comment: No, TuneUp doesn't make folders. However, if you let iTunes manage your music folder, it will automatically put the sorted files in artist / album folders, per the iTunes settings.

Comment: @RandolphWest How do I let  iTunes manage my music folder and where  will be music folder will be located on the drive?

Comment: That's all up to you. Under Preferences > Advanced, there's myriad options for iTunes Media folder location, whether to keep it organised, and whether to copy files to that location or leave them in their original location. I personally let iTunes handle everything, so when I import music, I delete the original tracks and let it copy everything where it wants to. One less thing to think about when backing up, because Time Machine (or Carbon Copy Cloner) backs up my entire library.